# Spring Boot 2 DataJpaTest Failed to introspect annotated methods due to ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm writing tests for the backend of a web service. In particular, the test is for our user repository. The test fails because the application does not run. The application actually works, so I know the dependecies are OK.

I'm new to spring boot, so I'm sure that I'm doing something wrong. I've spent the better part of the day reading the docs at spring.io and searching for a solution, but to no avail. I'd appreciate the help very much.

## Log

```
2020-04-29 18:25:33.011 ERROR 3812 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.anon.backend.Application]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotated methods on class com.anon.backend.Application
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:181) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:315) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:232) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:275) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:95) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:691) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:528) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) ~[spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) ~[spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:127) ~[spring-boot-test-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99) ~[spring-test-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117) ~[spring-test-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108) ~[spring-test-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:118) ~[spring-test-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83) ~[spring-test-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:44) ~[spring-boot-test-autoconfigure-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246) ~[spring-test-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227) ~[spring-test-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289) ~[spring-test-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291) ~[spring-test-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246) ~[spring-test-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97) ~[spring-test-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) ~[spring-test-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) ~[spring-test-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190) ~[spring-test-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89) ~[.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41) ~[.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:542) ~[.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:770) ~[.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:464) ~[.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210) ~[.cp/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotated methods on class com.anon.backend.Application
    at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.getAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:169) ~[spring-core-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.retrieveBeanMethodMetadata(ConfigurationClassParser.java:392) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:317) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:242) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:199) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:167) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    ... 38 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/jce/provider/BouncyCastleProvider
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3171) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2314) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.getAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:158) ~[spring-core-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    ... 43 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[na:na]
    ... 47 common frames omitted
```

## Application

```
package com.anon.backend;

import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import java.security.Security;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {
        "com.anon.backend", "com.anon.backend.error"
})
@EntityScan(basePackages = {
        "com.anon.backend.entities"
})
@EnableScheduling
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class Application extends ApplicationBase {

    static {
        Security.setProperty("crypto.policy", "unlimited");
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

## Test

```
package com.anon.backend.repositories;

import static org.junit.Assert.fail;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.TestEntityManager;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class UserRepositoryIT {

    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager em;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Test
    public void testGetByUsername() {
        // Create some users, get some users by their username, assert.
    }
}
```

## Repository

```
package com.anon.backend.repositories;

import com.anon.backend.entities.User;
import org.springframework.data.repository.Repository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery;
import javax.persistence.criteria.ParameterExpression;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Root;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Component
public class UserRepository extends BaseRepository<User> implements Repository<User, Long> {
    // Methods that get users from the DB.
}
```

Comment: The exception tells you what is wrong, you are missing a dependency in your test. The issue is that the `Application` class is loaded and thus the `static` block is executed (as well as all the imports get loaded and the annotations processed). another thing you don't need the `@EntityScan`, `@EnableTranscationManagement` or the `basePackages` in your `@SpringBootApplication`. Those are already implied by `@SpringBootApplication`.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks! My IDE wasn't running the test correctly, hence the missing dependency. It still isn't working yet, but I've made a lot of headway. Will post my solution once I've found it. :)